# Finding a curve which satisfies a special condition about angle

Tags: geometry, circles

We can see that the angle of 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{1-a^2}=1\ \ \ (0\lt a\lt 1)$$
from every point on 
$$C : x^2+y^2=1$$
is $\pi/2$.

$\hspace1in$[image]

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : If the angle of a figure $F$ from every point on $C$ is constant, then can we say that $F$ is an ellipse?

Here, suppose that $F$ is a simple closed curve on the coordinate plane, and that $F$ is strictly inside of $C$.

For a fixed point $P$ on $C$, let $L_P$ be the set of the lines from $P$ to every point on $F$. Also, let $\theta_P$ be the set of the angles, which include $F$, between every two distinct elements of $L_P$.

Then, suppose that the angle of $F$ from a fixed point $P$ on $C$ is defined as the maximum element of $\theta_P$.

I've been interested in this question, but I don't have any good idea. Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Even if we stick with $\pi/2$ as our angle, I'm not sure that the only such curve is an ellipse. There might be something clever that you can construct from circular arcs, analogous to a [curve of constant width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points from which a given curve are seen at a fixed angle are called isoptics.  If the angle is a right angle, they are called orthoptics.  These have been investigated by several authors.  The title of a paper by A. Miernowski ("Parallelograms inscribed in a curve having a circle as $\frac \pi 2$-isoptic") in Ann. Univ. Mariae Curie 62 (2008) 105-111, suggests that the answer to your query is negative.

Comment: I suspected that it's impossible for this topic to be uncovered at all :) thanks for the reference!

Comment: The paper is freely available [here (PDF file)](http://versita.metapress.com/content/rq740771043h5113/fulltext.pdf). But unfortunately there aren't any pictures. In fact I found it impossible to follow, but that's probably just me...

Comment: I found the following which are related to your problem.  "Conjectured isoptic characterisation of a circle (Klamkin, Amer. Math. Monthly 95 (1988) 845) and "Isoptic characterisation of a circle" by Nitsche (same journal, 97 (1990) 45-47.  It seems that you need to know that two isoptics are an ellipse to deduce that the curve is a ellipse.

Comment: @jena: Thank you very much for your answer and comment!

Comment: @TonyK: I found the following PDF which I found from the references of the paper jena wrote in his/her answer. This includes some pictures. http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0766-01.pdf